# How to change the Internet Explorer 10 default search engine to Google?

Tags: windows-8-preview, internet-explorer-10

When I'm browsing I always use the address bar to search, but when I do this in Internet Explorer 10, I get taken to the default search engine Bing.

So I started looking in the Internet Options to see if I could change it, but I couldn't find the right option.

[image]

There's no clear way to add Google from this screen and when I clicked: **Find more search providers...**, you get taken to [IE Gallery](http://www.iegallery.com/en-US/addons?callback=true&featuretype=2) where Google isn't even listed.

So how do I change my Internet Explorer 10 search engine to Google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google is listed, it is just hidden well!

[Here is the link for Goolge search](http://www.iegallery.com/en-US/Addons/Details/813) in the IE Gallery - Add it and you should be able to use Google from the address bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google search is not hidden at all - if IE thinks you are American. Just go to Regional & Language in Control Panel. On the Formats tab choose English (United States) and click Apply. Now you can use the original poster's method to add search providers and will be offered lots of choices. Afterwards, simply revert your format selection to reflect your own region.

Yes, I could offer further opinion on this and what it says about Americans but...

Answer (score 1):

The earlier answer regarding being in the US is on the right track.  If you are not in the US, you may see a much smaller list of search providers.  In Australia for example, Google comes up as only an "accelerator", but not as a "search provider" at all.

I found that the previous answer's suggestion to change "Region and Language" did not work for me. Instead I was able to see the much wider range of results by overtyping the language part of the URL which was displayed with the search results.  Eg. on my computer in Australia the URL was displayed as:

http://www.iegallery.com/en-au/addons?callback=true&featuretype=2

so I overtyped the "en-au" part with "en-us" and hit Enter.  Presto - many more search providers, including Google.

Answer (score 0):

Too old info. Had mine fixed by following this guide for internet explorer, chrome, firefox. Enjoy!

[How to change browsers search](http://www.squidoo.com/how-to-change-address-bar-search-on-firefox-chrome-internet-explorer)

Comment: Link only answers aren't good answers. If the link dies this answer becomes useless. Please summarise the page here.